# IntelliJ suddenly "forgets" SDK and Module when opening any project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, project, jetbrains-ide

All of the sudden with no warning, any project I open in IntelliJ opens the .iml file only. If I go into Project Structure and set the .iml file to the root for the module, I can get the project view back, but then it says the SDK isn’t defined. If I do that, it works again but I have to reopen each folder under src folder (my java classes) individually, and when I exit and come back in I have to do it all over again.

This is happening for every single project I try to open, and I haven’t messed with any settings to cause this. Do you know what I can do to fix it? I am having to redefine the root module and sdk every time I open a project rather than it using the defaults as they are set, so each time I open my project I have to define it all over again because it has “forgotten” the module and SDK. I saw a fix that said to back up and delete the .idea folder but it didn’t help anything so I’ve added it back.

As of now, any project I open, new or old, has no defined module or sdk, even though just yesterday any project would open without a problem.

EDIT: If it helps I also use Pycharm, which is also by JetBrains, and I am having no trouble with it.

Comment: Which version of  Intellij IDEA are you using?

Comment: Do you keep the project under OneDrive?

Comment: I do keep my projects in OneDrive. Is it not compatible with IntelliJ? I’ve been keeping them there since I got it and this is the first time I’ve had problems.

Answer (score 2):

Wow Yes, "one drive for business " causes this behavior oddly.

Fix:
Moving the entire folder to outside of one drive has 
fixed it, 
after 2.5 hours of experiments by two of us! 
 -Henry

Answer (score 1):

I disabled the "files on demand" feature in One Drive and that worked.